# How can we have SetDelayed insted Rule after solution of system equations?

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction

I write the following code:

```
Y[1] = 2*x[1] - x[2] + 1; 
Y[2] = 3*x[1] + 4*x[2] - 2; 
X = Array[x, 2]; 
T = Array[Y, 2]; 
Solve[T == 0, X]
```

I need to have the following answer:

```
x[1] := -(2/11); x[2] := 7/11;
```

This means that I need to  `:=` instead `->` and `;` instead `,`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: With `sol = Solve[T == 0, X][[1]]` do `sol /. Rule -> SetDelayed;` you'll get that `x[1]` will yield `-2/11`.

Comment: @Many thanks. What is `[[1]]`?

Comment: It's [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html), because `sol` is a nested list. And `/.` is [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html?q=ReplaceAll).

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate.  (See the banner link inserted at the top of your question.)  Please review that question and its answers.  If you have trouble adapting those to your specific needs let me know in a comment containing `@Mr.Wizard` (no code tags)